# where to place a controller helper class in a rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

My rails application has a json api.
Operation on this api may return an error. I'm currently using something like:

```
respond_with({:success=>false, :message=>"error_message"}, :status=>400, :location=>nil)
```

in the controller

I want to make this nicer. Therefore, I decided to create an error class, and its view, so I can do something like this in controllers:

```
error.new({message=>"my message", :status =>400})

render error
```

My question is. Where should I place this `ApiError` class?

I don't like to put it on models folder, because is kind of a helper for controllers for the api. Not a general application model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I namespace a class like this after my application and put it in `lib/my_app/`. For example if your app is `FooBar` I'd have a folder `lib/foo_bar/api` and define your class in `lib/foo_bar/api/error.rb` as

```
class FooBar::Api::Error
  # ...
end
```

This can be invoked with `FooBar::Api::Error.new(...)`

If you choose to go this route, you'll need to add `lib/` to your `config.autoload_paths` in `config/application.rb`

```
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib"]
```

---

> Do you know how could I make `render error` code return the error status code? not using `(:status => error.status)`

Sure, but to my knowledge you can't just pass `error`. You'd have to call something like

```
error = FooBar::Api::Error.new({ message: "Some error message" }, status: :bad_request)

render *error.to_a
```

You'd then have to define a `to_a` method on `FooBar::Api::Error`

```
class FooBar::Api::Error
  def initialize(data={}, options={})
    @data = data
    @options.reverse_merge! status: 200
  end

  def to_a
    [@data, @options]
  end
end
```

When you call `error.to_a` you'll get back an Array which will contain a list of arguments to pass to `render`. The `*`  on the render line above is the Splat operator (learn more [here](http://endofline.wordpress.com/2011/01/21/the-strange-ruby-splat/)), expanding the Array into a list of arguments to pass to `render` instead of sending the entire returned Array as the first argument.

Comment: Do you know how could I make "render error" code return the error status code? not using (:status => error.status)